# Start Dropbox on System Start (Not Login)

Tags: boot, dropbox

I am running Dropbox just fine on a 13.04 machine.  However, I want to be able to power up the machine, and have the Dropbox sync start automatically for a particular user (there is only one account on the box).

However, it only seems to start upon login, not start.  Is there a way I can start the Dropbox service for a user upon boot?

I am pretty sure that the 2nd checkbox below really means login, not boot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these [instructions](https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux) dropbox will start at boot (see the section **Dropbox Headless Install via command line**).

I am using it successfully on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

The only downside is that you won't be able to see the dropbox-icon in the indicator area anymore when you do login. This is okay in my situation, but might be a problem for someone else.

Comment: Just a follow-up.  This is working nicely.  I added the following cron-task to popup the status every hour.  Very unobtrusive.   notify-send 'Dropbox:' "`dropbox status`"

Comment: Your link does not seem to lead to useful instructions any more.

Comment: @Twinkles You are right. Thanks for reporting. I'm going to fix it.

Comment: There are headless installation instructions at https://www.dropbox.com/install-linux that should work.